# Mysql left join multiple columns from the same parent table

Tags: mysql, join

I'm having following problem with mysql query.

Given 2 tables

---

**Person**

Id | Name

1 | John Doe

2 | Jane Doe

3 | Pluto

---

**Tickets**

Id | Owner | Opener | AssignedTo

1  | 1     |  2     | 3

2  | 3     |  1     | 2

Owner, Opener, AssignedTo are Foreign keys linking to People Id

---

I need to make a query replacing Owner, Opener, AssignedTo columns with user names.

It's not a problem with just one column (it's enough to use left join), but I can't receive following output

select * from ....

1 | John Doe | Jane Doe | Pluto

2 | Pluto    | John Doe | Jane Doe

Thanks in advance.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334712/sql-server-update-from-select

Comment: Thx Mr Anderson, but I was looking for an select statement, not update :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could join `Person` multiple times.

```
SELECT t1.Id, t2.Name AS owner, t3.Name AS opener, t4.Name AS assignedTo
FROM Tickets t1
LEFT JOIN Person t2 ON t1.Owner = t2.Id
LEFT JOIN Person t3 ON t1.Opener = t3.Id
LEFT JOIN Person t4 ON t1.AssignedTo= t4.Id
```

Comment: Why not use p1, p2, and p3 for aliases for the Person table instead of t2, t3, and t4?

Comment: I suppose because i totally forgot about this possibility (shame on me)... Xdazz thanks, I'll accept your answer after 5 min (this timeout before accepting answer is kinda lame <.<)

Answer (score 0):

SELECT Tickets.`Id` , POwner.Name AS Owner, POpener.Name AS Opener, PAssignedTo.Name AS AssignedTo
FROM `Tickets`
JOIN `Person` AS POwner ON `Owner` = POwner.Id
JOIN `Person` AS POpener ON `Opener` = POpener.Id
JOIN `Person` AS PAssignedTo ON `AssignedTo` = PAssignedTo.Id